# Linux access() system call shows inconsistent behavior

Tags: linux

The system call access() reports: "No such file or directory", for some files/directories.
All directories/files have the requested permissions. Their owner/group is my login ID, as
is for the program posted below. Also, file manager shows all files/directories with correct
permissions, owner/group.

Specifically, for some subdirectories/files I get the error. But for the same subdirectories
that I got error on, all files (and subdirectories) show without error.

What am I missing please?

struct dirent *pDirent;

int main(int c, char** v) {

```
DIR *pDir = opendir(v[1]);
if (!pDir) {
    cout << "Could not open: " << v[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}

while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL) {
    if (pDirent->d_name[0] == '.') continue;

    if (pDirent->d_type == DT_DIR) {
        if (access(pDirent->d_name, X_OK)) {
            cout << pDirent->d_name << " Error: " << dec << errno << ' ' << strerror(errno) << endl;
        }
        else cout << pDirent->d_name << endl;
    }
    else if (pDirent->d_type == DT_REG) {
        if (access(pDirent->d_name, R_OK | W_OK)) {
            cout << pDirent->d_name << " Error: " << dec << errno << ' ' << strerror(errno) << endl;
        }
        else cout << pDirent->d_name << endl;
    }
    else continue;
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The name passed to access() should be absolute. In this case, it will be the concatenation of v[1], "/" and pDirent->d_name instead of just pDirent->d_name.